# How to find the location of a bash file?

Tags: bash, macos, jar, terminal

I've made an executable `.jar` file for a terminal game I've been working on. So far, I opened it by typing `java -jar name.jar` in the Terminal. This worked, but when I made a `.sh` file with the same command, the `.jar` file couldn't be accessed. It looked like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
java -jar game.jar
```

(doesn't work)

Later, I realized that if I specify where the jar file is, it does open.

```
#! /bin/bash
java -jar Desktop/playgame/game.jar
```

But the jar file and bash file are in the same folder, and if I were to move that folder elsewhere, that file path specified in the bash file won't be valid anymore.

*Is there a way to specify the location of the bash file, no matter where it is?*

I have used `chmod +rx bashfile.sh` to make the bash file executable.

I have tried it with a `.command` file instead of `.sh` file, it did the same.

Also, I'm on a MacOS Mojave 10.14.2 if that's of any importance.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itself

Comment: Also: [BashFAQ #28: How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

```
(printf '#! /usr/bin/env java -jar\n'; cat game.jar) > game
chmod +x game
```

and if `game`'s dir is in `PATH` you can invoke just

```
$ game
```